# Trying to insert data non related to model produces null

Tags: dukescript

I'm trying to type some numbers that are not directly related to the model based on [this example](https://gist.github.com/a083ada2ddd2a5ed3ee6).

### My code

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: screenText" />
<div>
    <div>
        <div data-bind="with: '1'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: '2'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: '3'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div data-bind="with: '4'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: '5'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: '6'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div data-bind="with: '7'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: '8'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: '9'">
            <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed"   href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<a>Llamar</a>
<div data-bind="with: 'hi'">
    <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.keyPushed" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

JAVA:

```
package dew.demo.namesmodel;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
import net.java.html.json.Function;

@Model(className = "Data", properties = {
    @Property(name = "screenText", type = String.class)
})
class DataModel {
   @Function
    static void keyPushed(Data model, String keyPress) {
        System.out.println(keyPress);
        model.setScreenText(model.getScreenText()+keyPress);
    }

   static {
    Data ui = new Data();
        ui.setScreenText("1");
        ui.applyBindings();
   }

}
```

As perhaps you may have notticed, the idea is to use the input as a display and append the key value when clicked.

¿Is this possible or do I have to take the approach to incluse it into the data model forcefully?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you're setting $data using the with-binding. So you want to access $data in your function. Do it like this:

```
@Function
static void keyPushed(Data model, String data) {
    System.out.println(data);
    model.setScreenText(model.getScreenText()+ data);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you :D